# Jquery AJAX call incomplete and yet JS statements allowed to continue?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Is JavaScript allowed to continue despite an unfinished $().load call? When I enter the following statements one by one into the Chrome JS console, the r_total element is properly populated. When I enter them as a duo, I get nothing.

```
$("#r_num").load("php/PHP_ajax.php"); 
document.getElementById('r_total').innerHTML = document.getElementById('r_num').innerHTML;
```

The PHP script I'm calling is very simply:

```
echo rand(1,25);
```

My suspicion is that the second statement launches before the first one is complete. Much thanks, as I'm quite new to web development. This is XAMPP on a Windows machine.

Comment: You want to go look up what the first “A” in AJAX stands for …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **A** in AJAX stands for asynchronous. So it doesn't block any other JS from running. If you need them to run in sequence, add the second statement as a callback function. [.load supports this](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$("#r_num").load("php/PHP_ajax.php", function() {
    document.getElementById('r_total').innerHTML = document.getElementById('r_num').innerHTML;
});
```